# c# WebBrowser no muestra paginas react app

Tags: c#, windows-forms, web, reactjs

Tengo un problema, anteriormente hice una automatizacion para navegar en una pagina y descargar unos archivos automaticamente con un WebControl en Windows Form y todo perfecto, ahora quiero hacer algo similar en una pagina que parece ser que esta programada con react js y al hacer pruebas el control no me carga o tal vez no sea soportado, hay alguna manera o algun control para detectar la pagina? igual cuando voy a la pagina y trato de inspeccionar el codigo fuente me muestra muy poca informacion.

Comment: No entendi quieres cargar un control Windows en una pagina web?

Comment: No, visceversa, cargar una pagina web en un windows form y controlar la navegacion mediante c# y controles de windows form, hice uno hace poco para que descargara facturas del sat solo ocultaba el webbrowser y asi el usuario solo veia los controles de windows form. Lo que sucede con esta otra pagina que quiero manejar de la misma manera es que no me la carga el WebForm.

Comment: Primero debes publicar tu contenido web y despues cargar ese contenido a windows form, pero no es recomendable.

Comment: Es lo que trato de decir que no me carga en el control webcontrol del windows form...

Comment: Ya tienes instalado el Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls en tu solucion? que version de Visual studio usas y windows.

Comment: la pagina puede verla correctamente en el IE ? prueba si puedes en el IE11 y en IE Edge, no recuerdo con cual se integra especificamente pero el engine que usa por detras es el de estos browsers, sino puedes verlo bien en estos entonces no podras verlo en el WebBrowser. Puede ser que uses alguna notacion ES6 que aun no esta implementada en IE, valida con la developer tools si hay un error en la consola

Comment: @LeandroTuttini la pagina opera normalmente, de hecho no es una pagina programada por mi, al utilizar el developer tools es donde me doy cuenta que esta programada en react js por que no me muestra la informacion de los controles ni nada como normalmente vienen otras paginas y creo que por esto posiblemente el control webbrowser no me la esta cargando.

Comment: opera normalmente en IE11 ?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini oh perdon, habia probado en Edge y Chrome y si me opera bien, pero parece que en ie11 no funciona, no me carga nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El control `WebBrowser` esta integrando con el engine de IE11, entiendo este tiene developer tools a ver si menciona la causa por la cual falla y si se puede resolver.

Sino vas a tener que cambiar de componente y usar uno basado en

[cefsharp](http://cefsharp.github.io/)

Esta libreria dice:

> CefSharp has browser controls for WinForms and WPF apps, and a headless (offscreen) version for automation projects too.
>
> CefSharp is based on Chromium Embedded Framework, the open source version of Google Chrome

Si en Chrome puede ver correctamente el sitio usa un compomente que use este como engine de base

Lo agregas usando nuget

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, ya instale esa libreria y ya me lo carga perfecto gracias, solo tengo el problema de como interactuar con la pagina si esta en codigo react jsx.